# How to efficiently identify duplicates and correctly recast a sequence of numbers in R?

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, sequence

I'm working on looping code in R that identifies any disallowed duplications in a sequence of numbers, and then reiteratively recasts the numbers into a correct sequence. As shown in the image below starting with the first step in an assumed loop, where `dat` is the initial data frame whose sequences are to be checked, `uniqCodes` isolates the unique Codes from `dat`, and then `ckDupes` counts any disallowed duplicates in column `cntDupes1`, reassigns the next sequential Code in those instances of disallowed duplicates in column `reCode1`, and then another check for disallowed duplicates in column `cntDupes2`:

[image]

Below is my code for these 3 data frames, that works in this scenario. Is there a more efficient way to do the duplication identification and resequencing currently done in `ckDupes`? This is the kind of tangled code that I won't understand a month from now and it needs to be clear and efficient since it'll be in an iterative process as I build out the loop.

Code:

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(Element= c("X","X","X","X","R"),
                  Code = c(1.1,2.1,2.2,2.2,3))

uniqCodes <- dat %>% select(Code) %>% distinct()

ckDupes <- dat %>% 
  mutate(cntDupes1 = sapply(1:n(), function(x) sum(Element[1:x]==Element[x] & Code[1:x] == Code[x]))-1) %>%
  mutate(reCode1 = ifelse(cntDupes1 > 0,uniqCodes[match(Code,uniqCodes$Code)+cntDupes1,],Code)) %>%
  mutate(cntDupes2 = sapply(1:n(), function(x) sum(Element[1:x]==Element[x] & reCode1[1:x] == reCode1[x]))-1)
```

Comment: What do you really want, or better phrased, what numbering you want as alternatives? `c(1.1, 1.1, 1.2. 2.0, 3.0)` for example, we have one duplicate for `1.1` (2nd element), do you want it to become `1.3` or `4.0`. To help you here some better examples and what your numbering system should look like would help us a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give a few options, at least they prevent to loop and recheck for new duplicates over and over again. Lets take this little expanded dataset.

```
dat <- data.frame(Element= c("X", "X", "X","X","X", "X","R", "Z", "Z", "Z"),
                  Code = c(1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0, 3, 3, 10, 4.4, 4.5))
```

**Using your code first**

```
uniqCodes <- dat %>% select(Code) %>% distinct()

dat %>% 
  mutate(cntDupes1 = sapply(1:n(), function(x) sum(Element[1:x]==Element[x] & Code[1:x] == Code[x]))-1) %>%
  mutate(reCode1 = ifelse(cntDupes1 > 0,uniqCodes[match(Code,uniqCodes$Code)+cntDupes1,],Code)) %>%
  mutate(cntDupes2 = sapply(1:n(), function(x) sum(Element[1:x]==Element[x] & reCode1[1:x] == reCode1[x]))-1)

#    Element Code cntDupes1 reCode1 cntDupes2
# 1        X  1.1         0     1.1         0
# 2        X  1.1         1     1.2         0
# 3        X  1.1         2     2.0         0
# 4        X  1.2         0     1.2         1
# 5        X  2.0         0     2.0         1
# 6        X  3.0         0     3.0         0
# 7        R  3.0         0     3.0         0
# 8        Z 10.0         0    10.0         0
# 9        Z  4.4         0     4.4         0
# 10       Z  4.5         0     4.5         0
```

Here we already see two serious issues in reCode1, you renamed the second 1.1 value to 1.2 while that already existed, then - imo not consistent - rename the 3rd 1.1 value to 2.0 which also existed.

Not sure on what conditions you want to rename or keep existing values or if it is not relevent at all as long they get a new unique code.

I use `data.table` below in my example with three variations to make them all unique. And here the three alternative Recoding suggestions.

1. RecodedAlt1 - we keep the unique ones per Element "as is" and we replace the duplicates with a new number **starting** from the highest value (after the digit) in the group.
2. We totally recode everything, starting with *.1 (RecodedAlt2) or *.0 (RecodedAlt3)

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

dat[, dup := duplicated(Code), Element]
dat[, c("x", "y") := tstrsplit(sprintf("%.1f", Code), "\\.", type.convert = T), by = Element]
setorder(dat, x, y)
dat[, max := max(Code), by = .(Element, x)]
dat[dup == T, RecodedAlt1 := (1:.N)/ 10 + max, by = .(Element, x)]
dat[dup == F, RecodedAlt1 := Code]
dat[, reCodedAlt2 := paste(x, 1:.N, sep = "."), by = .(Element, x)]
dat[, reCodedAlt3 := paste(x, 0:(.N-1), sep = "."), by = .(Element, x)]
```

**results**

```
dat

    Element Code   dup  x y  max RecodedAlt1 reCodedAlt2 reCodedAlt3
 1:       X  1.1 FALSE  1 1  1.2         1.1         1.1         1.0
 2:       X  1.1  TRUE  1 1  1.2         1.3         1.2         1.1
 3:       X  1.1  TRUE  1 1  1.2         1.4         1.3         1.2
 4:       X  1.2 FALSE  1 2  1.2         1.2         1.4         1.3
 5:       X  2.0 FALSE  2 0  2.0         2.0         2.1         2.0
 6:       X  3.0 FALSE  3 0  3.0         3.0         3.1         3.0
 7:       R  3.0 FALSE  3 0  3.0         3.0         3.1         3.0
 8:       Z  4.4 FALSE  4 4  4.5         4.4         4.1         4.0
 9:       Z  4.5 FALSE  4 5  4.5         4.5         4.2         4.1
10:       Z 10.0 FALSE 10 0 10.0        10.0        10.1        10.0
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought there is a more efficient way to do this. The code for my resequencing routine is more involved than shown in my OP and your data.table approach offers a much faster, cleaner way to do this. I'll need to play around with this a bit however as this is very new to me

Comment: It might even be more efficient, I just took a gamble on how you want to make them unique, with three different criteria for the numbering. Of course the code can be reduced if we knew which one you want. Also if you explain in more detail whether existing Code's need to remain unaltered if possible or if they can all be renamed, or any other criteria/priority you might have would help to provide a more efficient approach for your specific needs. The approache I took can also be done with dyplyr for sure, it is just my personal preference that I am more familiar with to use data.table.